# A more vernacular way of saying "adopt an alternative approach"?

Tags: expressions

I'm trying find a more vernacular way to express "adopt an alternative approach". The context is "Looks like a bit of a challenge there. Perhaps I should adopt an alternative approach?" and the expression seems too redundant. Is it correct if I change it into "go the other way round"? Thanks :)

Comment: "try a different way"?

Comment: "try something else"?

Comment: "try something new"?

Comment: Repent!  Change your ways!

Comment: "Switch it up" ? --need superfluous characters--

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic expression, particularly after trying multiple proposed solutions: "back to the drawing board".

> We tried sprays and traps for the ants.  I guess we're **back to the drawing board**.

A less idiomatic solution:

> We call an exterminator every year.  Maybe we should **try something new**.

A common way to describe changing a method:

> I've been going about this the wrong way.  I should try something new.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> Perhaps I should try something different?
>
> Perhaps I should look at it a different way?

Saying "go the other way round" would not be incorrect, but it doesn't mean quite the same thing as "adopt an alternative approach."  "Go the other way round" limits the alternative to the opposite of what you are currently thinking, whereas "adopt an alternative approach" allows anything except what you are currently thinking.

Answer (score 0):

***you must take the other door***

The details are within:-)

[The Hitchhiker's Guide to Negotiation: How to Get what You Want : Never Take 'No' for an Answer!](https://books.google.ca/books?id=DJWU5xQJ-7kC&pg=PA103&dq=%22take%20the%20other%20door%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mKY6VcueG-ewsASfzYDQCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22take%20the%20other%20door%22&f=false)
Ian Wilkinson 
Obviously he will tell you that the other guard will lie to you about which door to go out of (because the other guard always lies). Therefore **you must take the other door**.

Answer (score 0):

**take another route**

**choose another path**

You suggested "*go the other way around*" as an alternative to expressing what you want, this gives me the impression that you are trying to convey the idea of a path or route towards a goal.

Answer (score 0):

“Perhaps I should *consider another option*” or “… *consider other options*” if there are several to choose from.

“Alternative/s” might even sound better to you if used with “consider”:

“Perhaps I should consider the alternative(s)” / “… consider an[other] alternative” / “… consider other alternatives.”

Answer (score 0):

"You should consider changing tack".

Comment: Tack is often used in the sense you referenced. Oxford def of tack "A method of dealing with a situation or problem; a course of action or policy:"
as she could not stop him going she tried another tack and insisted on going with him

Comment: But 'changing tack' is the set phrase.

Answer (score -1):

Take the road less traveled.
*(courtesy of Robert Frost)*